# drawing onto UITableViewCell like Mails app

Tags: iphone, quartz-2d

So I'm trying to do something "simple" like the mails app where my UITableVieCell subclass tells the user how many items belong in that object.  So once I grab my cell, I do this:

```
if ([map.locations count] > 0) {
        UIView *locationsView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, LOCATIONS_VIEW_LENGTH, LOCATIONS_VIEW_LENGTH)]; // LOCATIONS_VIEW_LENGTH is 20.0
        locationsView.frame = CGRectMake((cell.contentView.frame.size.width - 45), (cell.contentView.frame.size.height - locationsView.frame.size.height) / 2, LOCATIONS_VIEW_LENGTH, LOCATIONS_VIEW_LENGTH);
        locationsView.layer.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor].CGColor;
        [locationsView.layer setCornerRadius:3];

        UIFont *arialFont = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:12.0];
        NSString *locationsText = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", [map.locations count]];
        CGSize locationsLabelSize = [locationsText sizeWithFont:arialFont constrainedToSize:locationsView.frame.size lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeTailTruncation];
        UILabel *numLocationsLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake((locationsView.frame.size.width - locationsLabelSize.width) / 2, (locationsView.frame.size.height - locationsLabelSize.height) / 2, locationsLabelSize.width, locationsLabelSize.height)];
        numLocationsLabel.text = locationsText;
        numLocationsLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        numLocationsLabel.font = arialFont;
        numLocationsLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        [locationsView addSubview:numLocationsLabel];

        [cell.contentView addSubview:locationsView];
    }
```

I originally tried putting this code in an awakeFromNib method of the UITableViewCell, but my `[map.locations count]` was always less than 0 even though in my configureCell method it was not.  Not sure why that is, in any case, I call configureCell in my cellForRowAtIndexPath method and it does the above code.  It looks pretty horrible.

Screnshot:
[image]

What does Apple do to make theirs so nice in mail?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer [simple-table-badges](http://www.tuaw.com/2010/01/07/iphone-devsugar-simple-table-badges/) link as it contains sourcode also.Hope helpful.

Also refer [@RedBlueThing ansswer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3689546/display-badge-info-on-uitableview) in link